# SharePoint 2010: Updating View Xml (Enabling Toolbar)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api

I am trying to enable View toolbar on my list views. But it seems not to be working. How can I get the code right?

```
/// <summary>
/// Handles the Click event of the btnEnable control.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
/// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
private void btnEnable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SPWeb spWeb = new SPSite(tbSiteUrl.Text).OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList spList = spWeb.Lists[lbLists.SelectedItem.ToString()];
        foreach (SPView spView in spList.Views)
        {
            EnableToolbar(spView.Title, spList.Title, spWeb.Url);
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Enables the toolbar.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="viewName">Name of the view.</param>
/// <param name="listName">Name of the list.</param>
/// <param name="webUrl">The web URL.</param>
private void EnableToolbar(string viewName, string listName, string webUrl)
{
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
                                             {
                                                 using (var spSite = new SPSite(webUrl))
                                                 {
                                                     using (SPWeb web = spSite.OpenWeb())
                                                     {
                                                         spSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                                                         SPList spList = web.Lists[listName];
                                                         SPView spView = spList.Views[viewName];

                                                         XDocument xDocument =
                                                             XDocument.Parse(spView.GetViewXml());

                                                         XElement xElement =
                                                             xDocument.Element("View").Element("Toolbar");
                                                         xElement.RemoveAttributes();
                                                         xElement.SetAttributeValue("Type", "Standard");
                                                         xElement.SetAttributeValue("ShowAlways", "TRUE");

                                                         spView.SetViewXml(xDocument.ToString());
                                                         spView.Update();

                                                         spSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                                                     }
                                                 }
                                             });
}
```

UPDATE:

```
using (var spSite = new SPSite(webUrl))
{
    using (SPWeb web = spSite.OpenWeb())
    {
        spSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

        SPList spList = web.Lists[listName];
        SPView spView = spList.Views[viewName];

        spView.Toolbar =
            @"<Toolbar Type=""Standard"" ShowAlways=""TRUE""/>";

        spView.Update();

        spSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }
}
```

Closer, but still not good.

This time, it did modified the view. I know it because, the second time I run the debugger, I did noticed the value of the SPView.Toolbar property changed.

But when I open the same page in the SharePoint designer, I do not see `<Toolbar Type="Standard" ShowAlways="TRUE"/>` but I see the default value as: `<Toolbar Type="Standard"/>`.

In addition to that, I do not see the toolbar on the list view page when I open the list view in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I had to do to make it work.

```
/// <summary>
/// Enables the toolbar.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="viewName">Name of the view.</param>
/// <param name="listName">Name of the list.</param>
/// <param name="webUrl">The web URL.</param>
private void EnableToolbar(string viewName, string listName, string webUrl)
{
    using (var spSite = new SPSite(webUrl))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = spSite.OpenWeb())
        {
            spSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

            SPList spList = web.Lists[listName];
            SPView spView = spList.Views[viewName];

            SPLimitedWebPartManager spLimitedWebPartManager = 
                web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(spView.Url, PersonalizationScope.Shared);

            foreach (WebPart webPart in spLimitedWebPartManager.WebParts)
            {
                if (webPart.GetType().Name.Equals("XsltListViewWebPart"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        MethodInfo ensureViewMethod = webPart.GetType().GetMethod("EnsureView",
                                                                                  BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                                                  BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                        object[] ensureViewParams = {};
                        ensureViewMethod.Invoke(webPart, ensureViewParams);

                        FieldInfo viewFieldInfo = webPart.GetType().GetField("view",
                                                                             BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                                             BindingFlags.Instance);

                        var view = viewFieldInfo.GetValue(webPart) as SPView;

                        Type[] toolbarMethodParamTypes = {Type.GetType("System.String")};
                        MethodInfo setToolbarTypeMethod = view.GetType().GetMethod("SetToolbarType",
                                                                                   BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                                                   BindingFlags.NonPublic, null,
                                                                                   toolbarMethodParamTypes, null);
                        object[] setToolbarParam = {"ShowToolbar"};
                        setToolbarTypeMethod.Invoke(view, setToolbarParam);

                        view.Update();
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }

            spSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`SPView.Toolbar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spview.toolbar.aspx) property instead. The property expects the `<Toolbar/>` CAML element and replaces the particular XML node in the underlying CAML fragment.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use that as it is read-only property: public string ToolbarType { get; }

Comment: Hmm, sorry for confusion. Let me think a while, we do that somehow in Mossquito.